# How to set drawer toggle icon (`hamburger`) for the ActionBarDrawerToggle v7 without toolbars

Tags: android

I'm using action bar from `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity` so my activity is declared like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
```

I'm reading the tutorial which shows how to add Drawer:

```
DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
```

This is for the `import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle`. Now I've decided to use `v7` since `v4` is deprecated, but the constructor for the `v7` doesn't accept icon for the drawer. I've googled and found that the solution is to use the constructor flavor that accepts `toolbar`:

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar, int openDrawerContentDescRes, int closeDrawerContentDescRes)
```

but I don't use toolbars. So I don't understand how I can set icon with `v7` without toolbars. Should I switch to using Toolbars?

Answer (score 5):

Hey you get the solution here..

```
private Toolbar toolbar;
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

if (toolbar != null) {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                toolbar,
                R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };

    // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}
```

This one is also a good approach, personally i use this one.

```
public class MyActionBarDrawerToggle extends android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle {

    public MyActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity activity, final DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar, int openDrawerContentDescRes, int closeDrawerContentDescRes) {
        super(activity, drawerLayout, toolbar, openDrawerContentDescRes, closeDrawerContentDescRes);

        setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.drawer_toggle);
        setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);

        setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            }
        });
     }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: thanks, can't check it since I'm not developing right now, but I've upvoted it

Comment: Thank you so much for this.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question at all